# Full shiro configuration in tapestry 5.3

Tags: tapestry, shiro, tynamo

I have an application in Tapestry 5.3.4 that's using the tapestry-security 0.4.6 plugin along with shiro 1.2.0 for authentication, and it works well. However, I would like to use EHCache to cache session data, and eventually to cluster a couple of instances on top of the cache. This is all possible with shiro, however it requires configuring via the shiro.ini, which is no supported in Tapestry. Is there a way to configure shiro in this manner from within the app, or to force loading the ini file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting hold of the `SecurityManager` and calling `securityManager.setCacheManager(new EhCacheManager())` should do the trick.